# iOS 14.5 - Podcast app does not show previously played episodes

Tags: podcasts

I updated my iPhone 7 to iOS 14.5. In the Apple podcast app, I am no longer able to find certain shows previously played episodes grouped together. Is there a way to see all the episodes of the show that I have listened to all grouped together even if I’ve deleted them from the downloads?

Before I updated iOS, I could see this information.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 14.5 there’s a setting to hide played episodes.
Check in the settings app under the podcast section if it’s turned on.